# Conversion Failed When Converting the Varchar Value 'NOTDEFINED' to Data Type Int

Tags: sql-server

I needed some help when joining two tables on customer number in SQL SERVER.

I have a customer number in int and the other one in varchar format, and I wrote this:

```
FROM dkdksjsj a
INNER JOIN blablabla d
ON d.custnr = CAST(a.custnr AS INT)
```

I get this message:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'NOTDEFINED' to
>   data type int.

How do I deal with this message? I am a newbie to casting and converting.

Comment: Error is very clear.  `custnr` column has `NOTDEFINED` data in it which cannot be converted to `numeric` value

Comment: I can convert the custnr in INTEGER format to varchar with CAST(custnr AS INT). I tried it and it works. Since I am learning casting, is there a way of casting the VARCHAR to INTEGER despite the "NOTDEFINED"  value?

Comment: Do you want to eliminate the `varchar` value

Comment: Why is the other one in varchar format? It should be int as well. And use `NULL`  not a  string "NOTDEFINED"

Comment: First of all - ***why*** is the `custnr` which seems to be holding numerical value a `varchar` datatype? ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use can use

```
CASE  WHEN (ISNUMERIC(a.custnr)) = 1 THEN CAST(a.custnr AS INT) ELSE NULL END
```

you can also use (Thanks to @NoDisplayName for giving useful comment)

```
case patindex('%[^0-9]%', a.custnr) when 0 then cast(a.custnr as Int) else null end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from dkdksjsj a
inner join blablabla d
on d.custnr=CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(a.custnr) = 1 THEN CAST(a.custnr AS INT) ELSE NULL END
```

Or in SQL Server 2012 and above:

```
from dkdksjsj a
inner join blablabla d
on d.custnr= TRY_CAST(a.custnr AS INT)
```

Comment: I know, but it might work for the OP. Have you got a better suggestion?

Comment: `case patindex('%[^0-9]%', a.custnr) when 0 then cast(a.custnr as Int) else null end`